# Indicator variables: processing substituted NAs in vector

Tags: r

I would expect that once the 0s are substituted to NAs, the following code would run smoothly. `table(x)` shows counts for 0,1,2,3. Why do I get the following error (when the code runs without the `tryCatch` call)? Thanks.

```
 Error in X[[v]] <- ifelse(x == v, 1, 0) : 
   attempt to select less than one element
```

Input:

```
 x <- c(NA,NA,1,1,2,2,3,3)
 x[is.na(x)] <- 0
 uniqs <- sort(unique(x))
 X <- list()
 for ( v in uniqs ){
    tryCatch({
        X[[v]] <- ifelse( x == v , 1 , 0 )
    } , warning = function(w){print(w)}, error = function(e){ print(v);print(sum(x==v)) },
    finally = { print('done') } )
 }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot address the 0-th Element of a List. So `X[[0]]` (first loop) doesn't work.
Without the tryCatch you X-List only has 3 Elements

**2 Solutions:**

Solution similar to yours:

```
for ( v in (uniqs) ){
  X[[v+1]] <- ifelse( x == v , 1 , 0 ) #Invreasing v by 1
  print('done')
}
```

Appending list Elements:

```
for ( v in uniqs ){
  X <- c(X, list(ifelse( x == v , 1 , 0 )))
  print('done')
}
```

Result (in both ways)

```
> X
[[1]]
[1] 1 1 0 0 0 0 0 0

[[2]]
[1] 0 0 1 1 0 0 0 0

[[3]]
[1] 0 0 0 0 1 1 0 0

[[4]]
[1] 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 1
```

Comment: Very helpful,thanks. I wasn't looking in that direction at all: I thought that 0 was a valid list element name (coerced into a string or something like that).